# How to update a button in pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I tried to modify a file to improve the program until I met a roadblock.

How do you update/restart a button in pyAutoGui?

This is the mini-code if you would like to fix it.
Please also present how it works.

I wanted to modify the program since the original is a dupe for Minecraft. I want to fix it so that I can adjust the delay for clicks and be able to change the keybind since the default is ALT and nothing more.

```
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
import threading
import pyautogui
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#For default key bind

key = 'alt'
def main():
#To loop everytime you want to change keybind
   def keybind(key, Duping):
           while True:
               return key.hotkeys['\t', '\n', '\r', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(',
')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
'8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`',
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~',
'accept', 'add', 'alt', 'altleft', 'altright', 'apps', 'backspace',
'browserback', 'browserfavorites', 'browserforward', 'browserhome',
'browserrefresh', 'browsersearch', 'browserstop', 'capslock', 'clear',
'convert', 'ctrl', 'ctrlleft', 'ctrlright', 'decimal', 'del', 'delete',
'divide', 'down', 'end', 'enter', 'esc', 'escape', 'execute', 'f1', 'f10',
'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f2', 'f20',
'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9',
'final', 'fn', 'hanguel', 'hangul', 'hanja', 'help', 'home', 'insert', 'junja',
'kana', 'kanji', 'launchapp1', 'launchapp2', 'launchmail',
'launchmediaselect', 'left', 'modechange', 'multiply', 'nexttrack',
'nonconvert', 'num0', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6',
'num7', 'num8', 'num9', 'numlock', 'pagedown', 'pageup', 'pause', 'pgdn',
'pgup', 'playpause', 'prevtrack', 'print', 'printscreen', 'prntscrn',
'prtsc', 'prtscr', 'return', 'right', 'scrolllock', 'select', 'separator',
'shift', 'shiftleft', 'shiftright', 'sleep', 'space', 'stop', 'subtract', 'tab',
'up', 'volumedown', 'volumemute', 'volumeup', 'win', 'winleft', 'winright', 'yen',
'command', 'option', 'optionleft', 'optionright']

            #A condition which the program starts, so it needs to be left.
               if event == (empty):
                   break

   #For a hotkey and a button    
   layout = [sg.Text('Set Hotkey to run: '), sg.Button(key.upper())],



      #Window and Event
   window = sg.Window('Window', layout, size=(450, 250), font='bold')
   while True:
       event, values = window.read()
       if event == 'key.upper()':
                   key = keybind(key, (empty))
```

Comment: the code looks imcomplete. for example the comment lines dont have `#` which makes it hard for users to replicate and assist with the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I will try and fix it for others.

Comment: It is okay, everybody starts somewhere.  You can edit the question by pressing the edit link below your question.

Comment: I copy and paste this into the editor (`vscode`) and the indents are incorrect, so it throws errors. the indents are important as they are the code blocks...

Comment: i also note that the only import that is used is `PySimpleGUI` so the others should be removed. Please create minimal code which describes the problem clearly.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it but this is the farthest that I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Friend your code is not complete.

If to update a button use example:

```
#Example 1:
if event == 'Button_event':
                window['Button_event'].update(disabled=True)
    #Disable the button
    
#Example 2:
    window['status'].update(background_color='#DAA520')
    #update color
    
#Example 3:
        window['status'].update('CONFIRM NUMBER')
        #update the text
    
#Example 4:
        window['status'].update(text_color='#000000') #Blue
        #updates the text color.
```

I don't know if that's it, but if it is, it helps.